# Maven-Jetty ERROR freemarker.runtime - freemarker.template.TemplateModelException

Tags: hibernate, maven, appfuse

I am getting following error message when i run mvn appfuse:gen-model

> 16:52:36,198 ERROR freemarker.runtime -
>   freemarker.template.TemplateModelException: Method public
>   java.lang.String org.h
>   ibernate.tool.hbm2x.pojo.EntityPOJOClass.generateJoinColumnsAnnotation(org.hiber
>   nate.mapping.Property,org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration) threw an
>   exception when i nvoked on Entity: com.igate.model.UserMaster
>           at freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethodModel.exec(SimpleMethodModel.java:13
>   6) ~[freemarker-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.MethodCall._getAsTemplateModel(MethodCall.java:93) ~[
>   freemarker-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89) ~[f
>   reemarker-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:93) ~[freem
>   arker-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:76) ~[freem
>   arker-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:196) [freemarker-2 .3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92) [freemarker
>   -2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:196) [freemarker-2 .3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.IfBlock.accept(IfBlock.java:82) [freemarker-2.3.8.jar :2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:196) [freemarker-2 .3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92) [freemarker
>   -2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:196) [freemarker-2 .3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.ConditionalBlock.accept(ConditionalBlock.java:79) [fr
>   eemarker-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:196) [freemarker-2 .3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.Environment.include(Environment.java:1375) [freemarke r-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:155) [freemarker-2.3.8.ja r:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:196) [freemarker-2 .3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.Environment.include(Environment.java:1375) [freemarke r-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:155) [freemarker-2.3.8.ja r:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:196) [freemarker-2 .3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92) [freemarker
>   -2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:196) [freemarker-2 .3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.ConditionalBlock.accept(ConditionalBlock.java:79) [fr
>   eemarker-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:196) [freemarker-2 .3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$Context.runLoop(IteratorBlock.java:160) 
>   [freemarker-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:351) [freemarker-2 .3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:95) [freemark er-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:196) [freemarker-2 .3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92) [freemarker
>   -2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:196) [freemarker-2 .3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.Environment.include(Environment.java:1375) [freemarke r-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:155) [freemarker-2.3.8.ja r:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:196) [freemarker-2 .3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92) [freemarker
>   -2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:196) [freemarker-2 .3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.IfBlock.accept(IfBlock.java:82) [freemarker-2.3.8.jar :2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:196) [freemarker-2 .3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92) [freemarker
>   -2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:196) [freemarker-2 .3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:233) [freemarker-2 .3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.BlockAssignment.accept(BlockAssignment.java:83) [free
>   marker-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:196) [freemarker-2 .3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92) [freemarker
>   -2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:196) [freemarker-2 .3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:176) [freemarker
>   -2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:232) [freemarker-2 .3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.TemplateHelper.processTemplate(TemplateHelpe
>   r.java:255) [hibernate-tools-3.2.3.GA.jar:?]
>           at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.TemplateProducer.produceToString(TemplatePro
>   ducer.java:67) [hibernate-tools-3.2.3.GA.jar:?]
>           at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.TemplateProducer.produce(TemplateProducer.ja
>   va:28) [hibernate-tools-3.2.3.GA.jar:?]
>           at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.TemplateProducer.produce(TemplateProducer.ja
>   va:103) [hibernate-tools-3.2.3.GA.jar:?]
>           at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.GenericExporter.exportPOJO(GenericExporter.j
>   ava:148) [hibernate-tools-3.2.3.GA.jar:?]
>           at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.GenericExporter.exportPersistentClass(Generi
>   cExporter.java:137) [hibernate-tools-3.2.3.GA.jar:?]
>           at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.GenericExporter$2.process(GenericExporter.ja
>   va:43) [hibernate-tools-3.2.3.GA.jar:?]
>           at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.GenericExporter.doStart(GenericExporter.java
>   :128) [hibernate-tools-3.2.3.GA.jar:?]
>           at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.AbstractExporter.start(AbstractExporter.java
>   :95) [hibernate-tools-3.2.3.GA.jar:?]
>           at org.appfuse.mojo.HibernateExporterMojo.doExecute(HibernateExporterMoj
>   o.java:228) [appfuse-maven-plugin-3.5.0.jar:?]
>           at org.appfuse.mojo.exporter.ModelGeneratorMojo.execute(ModelGeneratorMo
>   jo.java:183) [appfuse-maven-plugin-3.5.0.jar:?]
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
>   BuildPluginManager.java:134) [maven-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
>   .java:208) [maven-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
>   .java:153) [maven-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
>   .java:145) [maven-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
>   ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116) [maven-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
>   ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80) [maven-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThre
>   adedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>   [maven-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
>   eStarter.java:128) [maven-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307) [maven
>   -core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193) [maven
>   -core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106) [maven-c
>   ore-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862) [maven-embed der-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286) [maven-embedd er-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197) [maven-embedder
>   -3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0
>   _05]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
>   java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
>   sorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
>   cher.java:289) [plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:?]
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
>   a:229) [plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:?]
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
>   uncher.java:415) [plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:?]
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
>   356) [plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:?] Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0
>   _05]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
>   java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
>   sorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
>           at freemarker.ext.beans.BeansWrapper.invokeMethod(BeansWrapper.java:616) 
>   ~[freemarker-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           at freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethodModel.exec(SimpleMethodModel.java:11
>   3) ~[freemarker-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
>           ... 78 more [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 4.538 s [INFO] Finished at:
>   2015-05-19T16:52:36+05:30 [INFO] Final Memory: 22M/54M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.appfuse.plugins:appfuse-maven-plugin:3.5.0:ge n-model
>   (default-cli) on project fitnessAdmin: Execution default-cli of goal
>   org .appfuse.plugins:appfuse-maven-plugin:3.5.0:gen-model failed:
>   Error while proces sing Entity: com.igate.model.UserMaster with
>   template appfuse/model/Pojo.ftl: Me thod public java.lang.String
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.pojo.EntityPOJOClass.gener
>   ateJoinColumnsAnnotation(org.hibernate.mapping.Property,org.hibernate.cfg.Config
>   uration) threw an exception when invoked on Entity:
>   com.igate.model.UserMaster: wrong number of arguments -> [Help 1]
>   [ERROR] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run
>   Maven with the -e swit ch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to
>   enable full debug logging. [ERROR] [ERROR] For more information about
>   the errors and possible solutions, please rea d the following
>   articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutio
>   nException

Comment: My guess is this is happening because you have an object with foreign keys. There's a tip in the documentation that suggests a workaround. http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+Maven+Plugin

Comment: I am unable to locate the following file as mentioned in the document   src/test/resources/appfuse/model/Ejb3PropertyGetAnnotation.ftl

Comment: Run "mvn appfuse:copy-templates" to copy the Freemarker templates into your project.